XCompose: utf-8 char not working
When I switch to the bépo layout (setxkbmap fr bepo_afnor or via ibus), and press the key altGr+j I get an UTF-8 prefix FDD5, that is displayed for instance in firefox via: . The interest is that I'm then supposed to map it via the ~/.XCompose, like:
include "%L"
<UFDD5> <0> : "⁰"

to type ⁰ after pressing altGr+j 0 (where 0 is from the top row).
This used to work perfectly, but now this is not working anymore (for what I know, I just upgraded my NixOs system to b8697e57f1029).
Note that my file is properly recognized, for instance if I put in it:
<5> <5>: "⁰"

then typing 5 5 (using the numbers in the top row via shift+0, not the keypad, after running ibus restart) prints as expected ⁰.
Any idea what I did wrong?
$ ibus version
1.5.29

